# If I compare two strings in python I get false even if they are the same

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to compare two strings, one downloaded, one from a file, but the if-statement returns always false, even if the strings are equal.

Am I doing something wrong?
Is this a bug in Python?

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
import urllib2


jsonstring = urllib2.urlopen("https://xkcd.com/info.0.json").read()
j = json.loads(jsonstring)
current_xkcd = j['num']
print current_xkcd
with open ("xkcd.num", "r") as file:
        downloaded_xkcd = file.read().replace('\n', '')
print downloaded_xkcd

if current_xkcd == downloaded_xkcd:
        print "Already got latest xkcd"
else:
        print "Downloading xkcd..."
```

Output:

```
1515
1515
Downloading xkcd...
```

Comment: Maybe there are some secret hidden whitespace characters in the strings. Try `print repr(current_xkcd)` and `print repr(downloaded_xkcd)` to see if any tabs or whatever appear.

Comment: Like Kevin said, I bet there is a `\r` at the end.

Comment: Print `type(current_xkcd)` and `type(downloaded_xkcd)`.  You may have a string and a unicode string.

Comment: Maybe you shouldget some 3 or 4 downvotes just by suggesting that a language used in millions of applications in billions oof instances every day, in critical places, has bugs that would make a simple string comparison non  deterministc. No, this "is not a bug in Python"

Comment: @LarryLustig, seems quite possible, yes. But wouldn't the equality check succeed anyway in that case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`json.loads` translates the data to Python types.  You're looking at an integer and comparing it to a string.

Instead of just `print current_xkcd`, try `print repr(current_xkcd)` or `print type(current_xkcd)`, and do the same for `downloaded_xkcd`.

Comment: This appears to be the problem. I ran OP's code up to `print current_xkcd`, and printing its type does show that it's an int.

Answer (score 3):

Your specific problem is that you are not even comparing two strings to start with.

Json is a rich serialization protocol, and when you do `json.loads` with the downloaded data, whatever is numeric becomes a number of the appropriate type:

```
>>> import json
>>> import urllib2
>>> jsonstring = urllib2.urlopen("https://xkcd.com/info.0.json").read()
>>> j = json.loads(jsonstring)
>>> type(j["num"])
<type 'int'>
```

And in Python, unlike PHP, Javascript, shellscript, a string containing the "2" character does not compare equal the numeral 2. 
Just convert the number you've recorded in the file in an integer as well -so you are able to make the comparison:

```
downloaded_xkcd = int(file.read().strip())
```

But them, you might as well just store in the file a json representation of your data as well, or use "shelve" or "pickle" to store proper serialized data in your file, instead of doing it by hand - which leads to manual conversion strategies like your ".replace(...)" and mine "strip()"  - that can (and will) fail in a lot of corner cases.

Answer (score 2):

Did you even try string.strip() for removing whitespace from string? so try this

```
current_xkcd = current_xkcd.strip()
downloaded_xkcd = downloaded_xkcd.strip()
```

before comparing them

Comment: No, but I checked via `hd` if the output contains any whitespaces. It doesn't

Comment: JSON will convert his web data to a numeric data type., That is what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found the problem.

`json.loads()['num']` returned a int instead of a string.

fixed it by changing to `current_xkcd = str(j[num])`

Comment: Don't forget to mark John Y's answer correct for the benefit of the next user who has the same problem.